# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WIA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, .net, reference, interop, setup-project

I've an application using "Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0" to acquire images. In my Win 7 x64 developer machine it works properly but if I try to create a setup project an install it on another Win 7 x64 pc I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WIA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=a9bedaecc58d6a85'
```

My project Build platform is set to "x86", reference CopyLocal is set to true.

In the setup project I add the primary output and it imports all dll but not Interop.WIA!

What I miss?

**Update**

Here my setup project files list and WIA reference properties, interop is not detected!

[image: Project detail]

**update**

I tried to create a simple winform project, added reference setup created and interop reference has been detected! So the problem seems to be that my project "Primary Output" won't recognize interop reference!

Can I force it?

Comment: Where is Interop.WIA resolved?  GAC or bin? Can you show the fusion stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dll should be indeed added to the setup manually.